# Heroku Deployment 404 Error with Node.js and Express.js Server

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

Anyone willing to help with a Heroku Deployment?

When I run my local repo the server works great but once I deploy it on Heroku I get a 404 Error.

I am using Node.js Express Server.

The server console is suppose to generate: Listening on port 5000!

The error I get instead is: {"error":{"message":"Error not found in app.js"}}

Git Hub Repo
https://github.com/instant-help/instant-help-backend

Deployed Repo
https://thawing-river-10076.herokuapp.com/